# Why Scooby-Doo's protoplasmic soul considered as pure?

Tags: plot-explanation, scooby-doo

In *Scooby Doo (2002)*, *Scrappy-Doo* wants Scooby-Doo's protoplasmic soul to complete final ritual take over the world.

> And the leader needs to absorb a **purely good soul** to complete the
>   ritual.

[image]

Why Scooby-Doo's protoplasmic soul considered as pure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Because Scooby-Doo is an innocent and genuinely good character.

Humans are nasty greedy violent creatures. You saw how Shaggy got jealous about the girl, even when his lifelong friend tried to help him. Scooby, on the other hand, has the traits of an innocent loyal dog. He would never betray his friends (on purpose, at least) and he loves them all. He is not violent, he doesn't lie, he would never let down someone in need. He doesn't like being the center of attention, he doesn't boast, and despite being a big coward, he finds the courage to do the right thing.

He is quite the opposite of Scrappy, actually. Scrappy is an annoying inconsiderate jerk, who wants to take over the world.

Comment: `He doesn't like being the center of attention` Pretty much every old episode ended with Scooby Doo catching everyone's attention (usually by dressing up). He's not a dick about it, but he does _like_ the attention he gets.

Comment: I don't remember the cartoon too well (it's been a long time), but I always had the feeling he did it to make others laugh, not necessarily to get attention. But I was a kid back then anyway :P